# Mount Azure File Share on Databricks Cluster

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-databricks, mount-point, azure-file-share

I'm trying to mount an Azure File Share on a Databricks cluster and get a 'permission denied' error. `mount: /mnt/test: permission denied.` Adding the --verbose flag doesn't provide any additional information. Can someone please help troubleshoot?

The error appears when the mount is executed. `sudo mount -t cifs //<storage_account>.file.core.windows.net/test /mnt/test -o credentials=/etc/smbcredentials/<storage_account>.cred,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino,nosharesock,actimeo=30`

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/test
if [ ! -d "/etc/smbcredentials" ]; then
sudo mkdir /etc/smbcredentials
fi
if [ ! -f "/etc/smbcredentials/<storage_account>.cred" ]; then
    sudo bash -c 'echo "username=<storage_account>" >> /etc/smbcredentials/<storage_account>.cred'
    sudo bash -c 'echo "password=<storage_account_key>" >> /etc/smbcredentials/<storage_account>.cred'
fi
sudo chmod 600 /etc/smbcredentials/<storage_account>.cred

sudo bash -c 'echo "//<storage_account>.file.core.windows.net/test /mnt/test cifs nofail,credentials=/etc/smbcredentials/<storage_account>.cred,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino,nosharesock,actimeo=30" >> /etc/fstab'
sudo mount -t cifs //<storage_account>.file.core.windows.net/test /mnt/test -o credentials=/etc/smbcredentials/<storage_account>.cred,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,serverino,nosharesock,actimeo=30
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you start loading Azure Files to Azure Databricks, make sure the Azure Storage File module is installed.

To install Azure Storage File module, you need to use: `pip install azure-storage-file`

[image: 34054-image.png.]

Once module is installed you follow the stackoverflow thread to load the Azure Files to Azure Databricks.

[image]

For more details, please go through the link below and it has step by step instructions to set up the azure blob storage file share for your databricks cluster: https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-file-share/

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm able to upload files to the Fileshare using the Python SDK. The question is, whether is it possible to mount the Fileshare to a Databricks cluster?